# how to Reusing a cUrl context after doing a PUT request in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I have some code where I'm trying to reuse a curl context to do put requests and get requests. After each put request the get request fails with this PHP warning:

> curl_exec(): CURLOPT_INFILE resource has gone away, resetting to default

I could use the PHP shutup operator, but I would rather properly reset the curl context. Does anyone know how to do this? I could also use different curl contexts, but I would rather reuse the connection since the application is sending a lot of requests. I could keep the file handle open, but that seems like a hackish solution, especially since this is all wrapped up in functions so i can call *doPut*, *doGet*, etc

```
$curlContext = curl_init();
$fh = fopen('someFile.txt', 'rw');
curl_setopt($curlContext, CURLOPT_URL, $someUrl);
curl_setopt($curlContext, CURLOPT_PUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlContext, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
curl_setopt($curlContext, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $size);
$curl_response1 = curl_exec($curlContext);
fclose($fh);
curl_setopt($curlContext, CURLOPT_PUT, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curlContext, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlContext, CURLOPT_URL, $someOtherUrl);
$curl_response1 = curl_exec($curlContext);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. Made a mistake in the quick pseudo code I typed for this question. I meant CURLOPT_HTTPGET, not CURLOPT_GET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from PHP 5.5, [curl_reset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-reset.php) can be used to reset all previous set options.

For PHP < 5.5, Li-chih Wu's solution is a possible workaround.

Answer (score 2):

After fclose($fh), do curl_setopt($curlContext, CURLOPT_INFILE, STDIN);

Will avoid the "CURLOPT_INFILE resource has gone away, resetting to default" warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `curl_setopt_array` instead of re using the context

```
$file = 'log.txt';
$fh = fopen($file, 'rw');

$options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/lab/stackoverflow/b.php',
        CURLOPT_PUT => 1,
        CURLOPT_INFILE => $fh,
        CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => filesize($file),
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false
);

// First Request
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), $options);
echo curl_exec($ch);
fclose($fh);

// Secound Request
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = "http://localhost/lab/stackoverflow/c.php";
unset($options[CURLOPT_INFILE], $options[CURLOPT_INFILESIZE]);
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), $options);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: After set a value to CURLOPT_INFILE then curl_exec, and fclose the CURLOPT_INFILE file handle, next curl_exec call will complain about CURLOPT_INFILE resource has gone away.
I think razzard is asking about how to reuse the same handle after PUT, and you are not answering that question.